# If x is empty, show y in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two variables for a user profile. Ideally both of them are filled out, but how do I set it to show `:portfolio` if `:portfolio_title` is empty? Right now it would be blank.

```
<%= f.label :portfolio, "Personal Website Link" %>
<%= f.text_field :portfolio, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Example: http://IMDb.com" %>
<%= f.label :portfolio, "Personal Website Title" %>
<%= f.text_field :portfolio_title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Example: My IMDb Page" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this comment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field#1471-BEWARE-of-options-value-in-a-partial), you can force a value of the field if it doesn't have a value:

```
<%= f.label :portfolio, "Personal Website Link" %>
<%= f.text_field :portfolio, id: 'portfolio_link', class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Example: http://IMDb.com" %>
<%= f.label :portfolio_title, "Personal Website Title" %>
<%= f.text_field :portfolio_title, id: 'portfolio_title', class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Example: My IMDb Page", value: (f.object.portfolio_title.blank? ? f.object.portfolio : f.object.portfolio_title) %>
```

FYI your label is incorrect. It should be:

```
<%= f.label :portfolio_title, "Personal Website Title" %>
```

For more "live" functionality, you can use Javascript/jQuery that populates the Portfolio Title field when the Portfolio Website Link field changes:

```
$('#portfolio_link').on('change', function() {
    portfolio_title = $('#portfolio_title');
    if (portfolio_title.val() == '') {
        portfolio_title.val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! so that works, but i the user has to now save the profile twice for it to work. when they hit save the first time it fills the placeholder on the edit page, but then they have to hit save again for it to show up on the user.show page. any idea how to fix?

Comment: @rs19 You can use Javascript for a more live example. I added IDs to the form inputs to make it function but you can use the default values that Rails provides for the IDs instead.